# Not able to access data variable in script but can in html

Tags: vue.js

I have populated a data variable with an array, and can access its contents by using a v-for in the html, but I can't access any of the data in the variable within the script, and I don't know why.

```js
var result = [{
  "CatalogName": "Retro Doors",
  "ItemName": "French Doors",
  "ItemListPrice": "$461.00",
  "ItemType": "Oak",
  "ItemFeatures": [{
      "Features": "Door Quantity",
      "QTY": 2
    },
    {
      "Features": "Door Hinges",
      "QTY": 4
    },
    {
      "Features": "Door Knobs",
      "QTY": 1
    },
    {
      "Features": "Door Looks",
      "QTY": 1
    },
    {
      "Features": "Glass Panes",
      "QTY": 2
    }
  ]
}];
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  beforeCreate: function() {
    console.log("Before Created");
  },
  created: function() {
    console.log("Created");
    this.GetItemsList();
  },
  beforeMount: function() {
    console.log("Before Mount");
  },
  data: {
    itemPriceList: []
  },
  methods: {
    GetItemsList() {
      this.itemPriceList = result;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log("Mounted");
    console.log(this.ItemPriceList);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ itemPriceList[0].CatalogName }}
  <div v-for="item in itemPriceList">
    {{ item.ItemName }}
    <div v-for="items in item.ItemFeatures">
      {{ items.Features }} : {{ items.QTY }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in a variable name inside `mounted` hook - used with capital `I`.

In data: `itemPriceList`
In mounted hook: `this.ItemPriceList`

Should be the same as defined inside `data` property.

Comment: I'll accept as answer, I can't believe that I didn't notice that typo

Comment: Everything works until I populate the itemPriceList by using an ajax call, then I get errors and can't access the itemPriceList

Comment: Need to the code of AJAX call and assignment. Though it is out of the scope of current question. Might to post another one or start a chat.

Comment: I just posted a new question about it.